# Enter a text from one activity and display it in another activity without creating another intent or startActivity() method

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, textview

I am new to android and starting off in exploring things. I have my main activity as **FirstActivity** and corresponding **first_layout.xml**. whenever **Third Activity** button is clicked we end up in **third_layout** linked to **ThirdActivity.java** having a EditText view component through which we enter data and upon hitting **send** i am trying to change the text **THIRD** to the entered data. Note that I don't want to start a new activity by intent or make use of startActivity() as it would change the state of the FirstActivity 
**(** i.e upon click of **CLICK** button the message **Hello World!** changes to **Greetings** and then if i open ThirdActivity and send the data the state of **Greetings** should remain as it is, but if i use intent or startActivity() the state of greeting is overridden and displays from the first i.e. **Hello World!** which i dont want **)**  constantly trying to different approaches here, your help would be very much appreciated.

I have the code of FirstActivity and ThirdActivity and their Screenshots as shown below. Thanks in advance.

FirstActivity.java

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewX;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);
        textViewX= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.f_textView_1);
    }

    public void toggleMessage(View view){

        if(textViewX.getText().equals("Hello World!")){
            textViewX.setText("Greetings");
        }

        else if(textViewX.getText().equals("Greetings")){
            textViewX.setText("Hello World!");
        }

    }

    public void toggleActivities(View view){

        Intent intent = null;

        if( ((Button )view).getText().equals("Second Activity")){
            intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        }

        else if(((Button)view).getText().equals("Third Activity")){
            intent = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
        }

        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

first_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/first_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.badarikrishnasg.firstapplication.FirstActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/f_textView_1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/f_button_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/f_textView_1"
        android:text="Click"
        android:onClick="toggleMessage"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Move between activities"
        android:id="@+id/f_textView_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/f_button_1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/f_button_2"
        android:text="Second Activity"
        android:onClick="toggleActivities"
        android:layout_below="@+id/f_textView_2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/f_button_3"
        android:text="Third Activity"
        android:onClick="toggleActivities"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/f_button_2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/f_textView_3"
        android:text="THIRD"
        android:layout_below="@+id/f_button_3" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[Image of FirstActivity Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqhkc.jpg)

ThirdActivity.java

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity{

    TextView textview= null;
    EditText message_text=null;
    FirstActivity firstActivity;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third_layout);

    }

    public void sendMessage(View view){


        message_text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = message_text.getText().toString();

        firstActivity.displayMessage(message);

        LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();  
        View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, null);                       textview = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.f_textView_3);

        if(message!=null){
            if(textview.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                textview.setText(message);
            }
        }
        else{
            message="no Entry Found";
            textview.setText(message);
        }


        this.finish();
    }
}
```

third_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Enter Search word"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />

    <!--<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to Third Activity"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/t_textView_1" />-->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Image of Third Activity Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qB7c4.jpg)

Comment: Create a getter and setter in application class.. set the msg from 1st activity and get the msg from 3rd activity..

Comment: maibe you can use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` for this

Answer (score 0):

You could try to start your third activity with a `startActivityForResult(intent);`

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

You must write static method displayMessage like this

```
public static void displayMessage (String msg){              
            textViewX.setText(msg);              
    }
```

and call it in send button click listener like this

```
 message_text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 String message = message_text.getText().toString();

 firstActivity.displayMessage(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use startActivityForResult(intent);

**In FirstActivity :**

```
public void toggleActivities(View view){

        Intent intent = null;

        if( ((Button )view).getText().equals("Second Activity")){
            intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);

        }

        else if(((Button)view).getText().equals("Third Activity")){
            intent = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }


    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if(resultcode = RESULT_OK){
         if(requestCode == 0){
           final String message = data.getStringExtra("key_message");
            textview.setText(message);
         }else if(requestCode == 1){
           final String message = data.getStringExtra("key_message");
            textview.setText(message);
         }
       }

    }
```

**In SecondActivity :**

```
 public void sendMessage(View view){
        message_text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = message_text.getText().toString();

         final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key_message",message);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)
        this.finish();
    }
```

**In ThirdActivity :**

```
 public void sendMessage(View view){
        message_text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = message_text.getText().toString();

         final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key_message",message);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)
        this.finish();
    }
```